# How many times does the word 'अनन्त' (Ananta) come in the Vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, upanishads, sanskrit, words

I would want to know how many times does the name 'अनन्त' (Ananta) come in the Vedas?

Comment: My Qn is WHY???

Comment: Please be specific about which Veda you would want to know, Do you want the total in all four Vedas?

Comment: Yes,i want to know total in all four vedas.

Answer (score 2):

9 times in the R̥g-vedá śākala samhita

[image: Graßmann's Wörterbuch zum R̥g-vedá.]

Comment: Can you give me the reference of your claims?

Comment: @UtshaSaha Graßmann's Wörterbuch zum R̥g-vedá.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the number 9 in this picture. Where is it present @Hiraṇyagarbha ?